# Can I update a field using a Lookup in a Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow

I've read the implementation guide and a number of other resources.  I can't see how to use a flow screen to display an Account's name and Parent Account field, and then have the user select the Parent Account, using the Lookup. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.    You'll need to do the following after creating your new flow:

1. Create **Screen** item in your Flow and make it your "start" item
2. In the **Screen** settings, add a field with Input Type = Textbox and name it "ParentAccountSearchTerm" and mark as ***required***.   your users will enter part of the name, or you can default to the current account name.
3. Now, create a **Record Lookup** item to Account and add a filter for "Account Name" contains "***ParentAccountSearchTerm***". Name it "***ParentAccountSearchResults***"
4. Create another **Screen** and add a field  with Type = Dropdown List and name it "SelectedParentAccount" and mark as ***required***.  You will need to assign the ***ParentAccountSearchTerm*** to the Choices Settings
5. Now that you have the desired Parent Account, you can then assign the Account.Id to your Current Account using an Assignment and Record Update Item

you'll have to make sure your flow receives the current accountId as a variable.   to display the name, simply use a record lookup and sotre the result in text variables, which can then be displayed on a screen as "display text"

Comment: I thought something like this would be necessary. I was hoping to use the normal lookup that you get with an SObject field like Account.ParentId. I guess that isn't the *flow* way. Unless another answer turns up.

Comment: Yeah, there's always some tradeoff when things are easier, such as less robust features...